# Most appropriate place to expect answers that fit on POSIXism?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I mean the word POSIXism (or POSIX fundamentalism or POSIX centralism) by *a programming method to depend on POSIX features only as well as possible to make your programs compatible and sustainable*, as in [this](https://gist.github.com/GH-TpaeFawzen/7979c8ce2cc9df8bb873991f5d4a20b6) (my unofficial translation, [original (Japanese)](https://www.ipsj.or.jp/dp/contents/publication/32/S0804-R1601.html)).
The method specifies POSIX-compliant shell language and POSIX-cpmpliant utilities to be first language for programming.
Though many things such as CSV/XML/JSON parsers, RDBMS-like system, random number generator, mktemp, zenkaku/hankaku converter, file locking, cookie generator, web session manager, MIME generator and decoder, base64, and CGI variable reciever/givener can be done within the range of POSIX, some processings such as fast binary manipulation and networking require some non-POSIX-compliant utilities. With those, many things such as Twitter client, sendjpmail, and PDF generator can also be made.

So far I have asked things that had never been tried for the method to expand its theory on Unix & Linux and Super User Stack Exchanges, but I found it very difficult to recieve answers I expect.
Every time I ask things, the post becomes a discussion rather than a place for Q&A.
Am I missing more appropriate places?

Comment: Its very hard to actually get an answer in a *specific* way - people solve problems the 'easiest', not the 'most portable' or 'posix-ideologically pure' way. Maybe if you want to burn rep with bounties...

Comment: So should I go to discussion sites and forum sites to leave stack exchange communities?

Comment: Well if you want to do it that way, maybe have your questions focus on specific parts of the pipeline - as opposed to the whole way of doing it